# cats-core_2.11-0.4.1: cats.instances not found

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have added cats-core_2.11-0.4.1.jar to my scala project, and I can import cats.Monoid, cats.Semigroup. But cats.instances is not found. Do I need another version of jar?

So I updated  scala  to 2.13 and cats to 2.3. Code:

```
import cats.Monoid
import cats.instances.int._

Monoid[Int].combine(32, 10)
```

But combine is not found now.

Comment: **cats** is currently at version `2.3.0` and you are using `0.4.1` which was released on February 2016! - It wouldn't be a surprise that most of the things will not work, try to upgrade to the latest version possible. - It would also be goo to try to use **Scala** `2.13` or at least `2.12` instead of `2.11`

Comment: So I updated  scala  to 2.13 and cats to 2.3. Code:import cats.Monoid
import cats.instances.int._ // for Monoid
Monoid[Int].combine(32, 10)

Comment: Since `2.2.0` the instances of the stdlib types are always in scope, so you only need to do this: `ìmport cats.syntax.all._` `val result = 32 |+| 10` and it will work. More information in the [release notes](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases/tag/v2.2.0).